# (WPF) How to ping from a class in c#?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm creating a WPF tool to use on my HelpDesk team using XAML and C#, but I'd like to improve upon what I've done.  I've got a textbox to enter a hostname, a button to start a ping, and a textbox that will keep pinging that hostname until I press the button again.

I'd like to keep the functionality the same, but I know there's a better way to write this code.

Currently, I have a class that pings the server and returns a response ONE single time. My main form calls this class, the logic is not written in the main form.  When I tried to make this loop, it just kills the function after the first run through rather than looping. The way I got it to work was by using a timer to call the function/ping class every 500 MS or so, and stopping the timer by clicking the button again.

Here's my current way of doing this, t stands for "timer":

```
 private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PingClass pingClass = new PingClass();
        _richtext.AppendText(pingClass.PingHost(_textBox.Text));
        _richtext.ScrollToEnd();
    }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)_pingBtn.Content == "Ping")
        {
            _richtext.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _pingBtn.Content = "Stop Ping";
            t.Interval = 500;
            t.Tick += onTick;
            t.Start();
        }
        else if ((string)_pingBtn.Content == "Stop Ping")
        {
            _richtext.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _pingBtn.Content = "Ping";
            t.Stop();
        }
```

The class itself is pretty simple, it just returns a string of whatever the response from the host is. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow me to loop through inside the class because it stops at the first return.  I'd like to gather an "average ping" and some other stats, but can't with the way it's currently set up. I don't want to have a timer, I want to be able to loop in the class itself until the button in the main form is pressed. Is this possible?

Comment: If your only question is "how can I improve this?", you're probably better off posting your full code over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could start off by declaring the `PingClass` instance outside the timer tick. Every timer tick a new one will get created.

Comment: First of all, create a unique PingClass in your form. Then add a timer inside of your PingClass with an event that send the average time. Then you just have to handle this event in your form and stop your PingClass when you press the button.